# Add emojis to Slack in bulk

Tags: slack, emoji

I feel expressively restricted by the emojis that come with slack by default.  I want to `:party_parrot:` and `:table_flip:` - I want to *live*!

But I *do not* want to add custom emojis one by one.  How do I add whole bundles to my slack channel?

Comment: There's a Chrome extension called "Save All Resources" that gives you the browser cache (so no admin privileges needed). I wrote a python script to reformat the files and get the emojis here: https://medium.com/@dan.chiniara/how-to-bulk-transfer-slack-emojis-without-admin-privileges-e0eb866770b3

Answer (score 1):

[Try setting up slack-emojinator](https://github.com/smashwilson/slack-emojinator) to accomplish this.

Once you've set this up successfully, you'll be able to bulk upload Slack emoji via a command like `pipenv run python upload.py ${EMOJI_DIR}/*.png`.